# Why does my python function remember a "set" variable?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to run a recursive program that takes an element and iterates over similar elements contained in it but never repeating. I want to keep track of the checked elements with a set type object and I want to repeat the process as many times as I want. This is my code

```
def assaignPuntuation(song, assigned={"0"}):
 if( song in assigned ):
  return  assigned 
 assigned.add(song)
 def runthrough(songlist, song, assigned):
  for element in songlist:
   assigned = assaignPuntuation (song,assigned=assigned)
  return assigned
 ...
 assigned = runthrough (song, song[4], assigned)
 ...
 return assigned

assaignPuntuation(A)
assaignPuntuation(B)
```

B is contained in the songlist of A, but when it is not indicated it should not start with all the songs checked in A, but it does.

I expected the set to start with {"0"} every time the function was called with only the song, but it saves the value the first time so I can't repeat it a second time. I tried changing the name of the variables to be different, but it keeps happening and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a function, the function header is executed once at the start of your program.
So in your case

```py
def assaignPuntuation(song, assigned={"0"}):
```

creates a function object with an initialised set for your default argument `assigned`.

That is why every subsequent call of `assaignPuntuation` gets the initally initalized `assigned` set which you mutate inside your function.

To avoid this unexpected mutation follow this approach when dealing with mutable data types:

```py
def assaignPuntuation(song, assigned=None):
    if assigned is None:
        assigned = {"0"}
    # Rest of your function
```

Comment: Thank you, that answer really helped me understand what is happening!